# Trying to output first_page and last_page pagination links when there's less than four pages

Tags: channel-entries, pagination

I've been having problems getting the first_page and last_page pagination links to work correctly. I then spotted a user comment [in the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/pagination_page.html) that said they only appear if there's four or more pages (though I hoped this just applied to the auto-generated pagination_links variable). I'm trying to output them at all times and thought the pagination variables would give me that flexibility.

I've inserted my code below - can anyone see if I'm doing anything wrong here? Or is there another way to be going about this? Or is it by design or a bug that the first_page and last_page only work when there's four or more pages? The links do indeed work when there's 4 or more pages.

```
{paginate}
  {pagination_links}
    <div class="search-pagination">
      <ul>
        <li class="first"><a href="{first_page}{pagination_url}{/first_page}">First</a></li>
        <li class="prev"><a href="{previous_page}{pagination_url}{/previous_page}">Previous</a></li>
        <li class="page-info">Page {current_page} of {total_pages}</li>
        <li class="next"><a href="{next_page}{pagination_url}{/next_page}">Next</a></li>
        <li class="last"><a href="{last_page}{pagination_url}{/last_page}">Last</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--search-pagination-->
  {/pagination_links}
{/paginate}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a conditional like this:

```
{if next_page}
    CODE
{if:else}
    CODE
{/if}
```

If that doesn't work, you'd need to hack the \system\expressionengine\libraries\EE_Pagination.php file.

Or take a look at some of the pagination addons on [**Devot-EE**](http://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=pagination&collection=addons&addon_version_support=ee2).

Comment: The problem is that the code itself for first_page and last_page generates nothing unless there's at least four pages, so even if you stick it within conditionals, it outputs nothing within them. I'm classing this as a bug, and a hang-over from the pagination_links single variable behaviour. I've filed a bug report here: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19221 Think the pagination add-ons is the way to go for now, thanks.